# Updating a particular product in cloud firestore in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to update a particular product in cloud firestore

I have a component with an edit button so when I click on it I am being routed to new component which has a form with all the previous details in it and also a bootstrap card

Screen shot is given here to clear any confusion: https://ibb.co/M5bvCBq

Now I make changes in the form here and submit it and then after submitting w want to update my particular data in my database So how can I achieve this?

service file

Here I am having update method which has 2  arguments

1. the data selected on clicking the edit button
2. automatically generated id that firestore gives us

```
    export class ItemsService {
    private itemscollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>
    datacollection:AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>
    items:Observable<any[]>
    alldata:Observable<any[]>
    updatepro

    constructor(public afs:AngularFirestore,db:AngularFirestore) { 
    }

    getitems(){
    this.itemscollection=this.afs.collection<any[]>('categories')
    return  this.items=this.itemscollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions=>actions.map(a=>{
    const data=a.payload.doc.data() ;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
    }))
    )

    }

    adddata(data){ 
    this.datacollection=this.afs.collection<any[]>('data')
    this.datacollection.add(data)
    }

    getdata(){
    this.datacollection=this.afs.collection<any[]>('data')
    return  this.alldata=this.datacollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions=>actions.map(a=>{
    const alldata=a.payload.doc.data() ;
    const idofdata = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { idofdata, ...alldata };
    }))
    )}

    update(data,id){
    console.log(data,id)
    }
    }
```

How can I update the data in my firebase inside update method?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your attempt to implement update (preferably with readable indentation, the current formatting is perverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
update(data, value){
return this.afs.collection('data').doc(id).set(value);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Inside update method pass the arguements data and value like

```
update(data,value){
 }
```

and then inside this return via targeting the id through doc and setting value through value

```
return this.afs.collection('data').doc(id).set(value);
```